# Custom spacing for each cell in Grid

Tags: grid-layouts, spacing

How to control the spacing of each cell in a grid?

In the example below, Title and Subtitle rows waste too much space above and below.

Also the rectangle in cell {4,1} is rather small, how to change its size?

Also the SpanfromBoth does not seem to work well since a vertical line shows up between cells {6,1} and {6,2}, and also between {6,4} and {6,5}.

```
title = Text[Style["Title", 26, Black], {0, 0}, {0, 0}];
subtitle1 = Text[Style["Subtitle 1", 26, Black], {0, 0}, {0, 0}];
subtitle2 = Text[Style["Subtitle 2", 26, Black], {0, 0}, {0, 0}];
Grid[{
  {Graphics[{title}], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[subtitle1], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   Graphics[subtitle2], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 1}]], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 1}]], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[]], SpanFromLeft, Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[]], SpanFromLeft, Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
  {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth, Graphics[Rectangle[]], SpanFromAbove, 
   SpanFromBoth, Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[]], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I discovered I could play with individual AspectRatios and Imagesizes:

```
title = Text[Style["Title", 26, Black], {0, 0}, {0, 0}];
subtitle1 = Text[Style["Subtitle 1", 26, Black], {0, 0}, {0, 0}];
subtitle2 = Text[Style["Subtitle 2", 26, Black], {0, 0}, {0, 0}];
Grid[{
  {Graphics[{title}, AspectRatio -> 0.1], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[subtitle1, AspectRatio -> 0.1], SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft, Graphics[subtitle2, AspectRatio -> 0.1], 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 1}], ImageSize -> 600], 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6, 1}], ImageSize -> 600], 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 200], SpanFromLeft, 
   Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 200], 
   SpanFromLeft, Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
  {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth, Graphics[Rectangle[]], SpanFromAbove, 
   SpanFromBoth, Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
  {Graphics[Rectangle[], AspectRatio -> 0.2, ImageSize -> 700], 
   SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I thought the rectangles were just there to show the grid structure and avoid distracting data. But yes, sizing the individual cell contents is an option. You might also be interested to know that for any particular cell, you can wrap the contents in Item and then provide any Grid options directly to that Item.

Comment: And of course there is the Spacings option, for another level of control of the layout. And sometimes Dividers works better than Frame (and maybe that would provide a workaround for your stray vertical lines--I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the stray vertical line (I'm using version 13).

The title and subtitle are large because you're creating graphics. If that's not necessary in your context, then just using Style should work:

```
title = Style["Title", 26, Black];
subtitle1 = Style["Subtitle 1", 26, Black];
subtitle2 = Style["Subtitle 2", 26, Black];
```

For the other sizing issue, Grid has an ItemSize option. It has many forms, so you should research it, but in your specific case this works to change the height of the 4th row:

```
ItemSize -> {{}, {4 -> 10}}
```

Replace the 10 with whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, I am using 12.3